# XCode 7.3 storyboard kept showing loading revision

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

Two days ago i have updated my Xcode to the version 7.3. It was working fine till yesterday. Today when I was opening a storyboard ViewController in editor(View > Assistant Editor > Show Assistant Editor), my storyboard got converted into the xml source code, and after that it kept showing loading revision, but nothing happens. I am afraid that, closing Xcode might be leads to loose my Storyboard or any unexpected behaviour. So I kept it open, Please suggest me any workaround, its happening since 10 minutes. Attaching screenshot for better understanding.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Select your storyboard
- Menu > View > Standard Editor > Show Standard Editor

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the storyboard file and choose `open as` -> `Interface Builder - Storyboard`.